# Custom ArrayList class

Tags: c++, memory-optimization

Please review my custom `ArrayList` class I constructed from scratch and add any suggestions or constructive criticisms. The point of this template class is give the user a lightweight `ArrayList` with optimal control over how it operates.

It is automatically created on the heap with an optional seed value which determines how much space to give it upon being recreated after filling up. It comes with a refine function which cuts off the garbage values at any time and it can also be reseeded. Seed default is 10 new array spots for each recreation.

```
#ifndef MEMORYLIST_H
#define MEMORYLIST_H

//Class is designed to be a basic array list off the stack
template <class Heap> class MemoryList {
private:
    Heap *array;    //ArrayList on Heap
    int length;     //Max Length of ArrayList
    int counter;    //Current Position on ArrayList
    int seed;       //amount to add by when limit is breached

    //Increase list if needed
    inline void spaceCheck() {
        if (counter == length) {
            int i;

            Heap *temp = new Heap[length];

            for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
                temp[i] = array[i];
            }

            delete [] array;

            length += seed;
            array = new Heap[length];

            for (i = 0; i < length - 10; ++i) {
                array[i] = temp[i];
            }

            delete[] temp;
        }
    }

    inline void shiftRight(int place) {
        for (int i = length - 1; i >= place + 1; --i) {
            array[i] = array[i - 1];
        }
    }

public:
    MemoryList(int seed = 10) {
        this->seed = seed;
        length = seed;
        counter = 0;
        array = new Heap[length];
    }

    //just shows what value is stored in what position
    Heap showValue(int position) {
        return array[position];
    }

    //tack a value to the end
    void newValue(Heap variable){
        spaceCheck();

        array[counter] = variable;
        ++counter;
    }

    //tack a value anywhere you want and array will self adjust
    void insertValue(int position, Heap variable) {
        spaceCheck();
        shiftRight(position);

        array[position] = variable;
        ++counter;
    }

    //delete any value you'd like and array will self adjust
    void deleteValue(int position) {
        for (int i = position; i < length - 1; ++i) {
            array[i] = array[i + 1];
        }

        --counter;
    }

    //Overwrite any value you'd like, no need to adjust anything
    void overWrite(int position, Heap variable) {
        array[position] = variable;
    }

    //swap any two array points
    void swap (int position1, int position2) {
        Heap temp;
        temp = array[position1];
        array[position1] = array[position2];
        array[position2] = temp;
    }

    //reseed amount of space you'd like to allocate when you're running out
    //of room
    void reSeed(int seed) {
        this->seed = seed;
    }

    //is item in array?
    bool search(Heap item) {
        //this might make it faster ::shrug::
        for (int i = 0, j = counter; i < counter; ++i, --j) {
            if (array[i] == item || array[j] == item) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    //Creates perfect ArrayList stored on heap without garbage
    void refine() {
        int i;

        length = counter;     
        Heap *temp = new Heap[length];

        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            temp[i] = array[i];
        }

        delete [] array;
        array = new Heap[length];

        for (i = 0; i < length; ++i) {
            array[i] = temp[i];
        }

        delete[] temp;
    }

    void finished(){
        delete[] array;
    }
};

#endif // MEMORYLIST_H
```

Comment: Unfortunately this question appears to be off topic because it is about understanding code. [The point of a code review is to identify things about the code that can be improved and discuss possible improvements](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/198/are-what-does-this-code-do-questions-on-topic-here).

Comment: Sorry, completely new user. Won't happen again, although could you possibly point me toward a more proper forum or subforum?

Comment: [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/) would be a good place. Possibly also [programmers.stackexchange.com](programmers.stackexchange.com). (Though I'm unclear on whether this question would be [on topic](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) there, since it sounds like an implementation issue.)

Comment: I edited your question to make it, in my opinion, on-topic for Code Review. For the part that I edited out, I suggest you post on Stack Overflow

Comment: @user1118321 This does not belong on Programmers.

Comment: Fair enough. I wasn't sure if it counted as an architectural issue or more of a coding issue.

Answer (score 6):

A couple of things jump out:

Use `size_t` for the all allocation sizes/indices. I *have* had real-world bugs because of this in third-party libraries.

Use exponential, not linear, reallocations. Doubling each time is the best way. This allows `.newValue` to append in \$O(1)\$ amortized time, as opposed to the current \$O(n)\$.

Comment: Apparently, [doubling each time is *not* the best way](https://github.com/facebook/folly/blob/master/folly/docs/FBVector.md#memory-handling), it may even be the worst growth factor :)

Comment: @Morwenn I'm not aware of a single real-world memory allocator that would even *try* to coalesce. They use *separate* bins for each size, though once it gets past the `mmap` threshold the kernel can give new virtual address space from anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

This is an excellent exercise! I wish I'd tried something like this when I first learned C++. Overall, this code is very straightforward and easy to understand. I was easily able to figure out what everything does. Nice work!

I have a few suggestions on how you could improve it in addition to what @o11c suggests.

**Naming**

The use of the name `Heap` is a bit strange. The word "heap" describes a few important things in computer science, and this doesn't seem like either of them. The heap is the area of memory where things that need to outlive the scope of where they're declared are allocated, and there's also an organizational structure called a heap (i.e.the [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heap_(data_structure)) used in [heapsort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heapsort)). Traditionally, the type used in a template definition is `T`. I'd stick with that.

Likewise, the name `MemoryList` makes me think that its implementation is a linked list. A linked list has certain properties that make it inappropriate for some uses, so it might affect when I would use it. Also, all your data for a class like this is in memory, so the word "Memory" in the name seems redundant. A better name might be something like `ResizableArray` or `AutosizingArray` or something like that.

Your `showValue()` method doesn't show anything. It just returns the value at the index. I'd rename it `valueAtIndex()`. Or better yet, maybe implement the `operator[]()` so a user of this class can use it like a normal array:

```
MemoryList<some type> foo(100);
...
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    std::cout << "Item " << i << " = " << foo [ i ] << "\n";
}
```

The name `newValue()` makes it sound like it returns a new value. I'd rename it `append()`. The standard template library uses `push_back()`, which I find cumbersome, but users of STL would know what it means.

The name `refine()` doesn't tell me much about what it does. Maybe `compact()` or `removeUnusedSpace()` or something like that would be more telling?

Also, why is there a `finished()` method? Why not just implement a destructor which `delete`s the array?

**Error Handling**

What happens when a caller calls `insertValue()`, `deleteValue()`, `overWrite()`, or `swap()` with indices that are not valid? They could be negative or past the end of the array (either in the allocated-but-unused area, or past the end of the allocated area altogether). You need to either return a value that indicates whether the operation succeeded, or you need to throw an exception when something goes wrong. An exception is probably a better choice here, but there are trade-offs. You should read up on them to see which is best for your use-case.

**Iterators**

I've mentioned a few features of C++ you could use to improve this, but there are more. Most container classes implement `iterators`. An `iterator` can be used for a variety of tasks, but is most often used to iterate though all members in a container in a loop like this:

```
MemoryList<someType> foo(100);
... insert various things into foo ...
MemoryList::iterator iter = foo.begin();
while (iter != foo.end())
{
    someType nextItem = *iter;
    ... do something with next Item ...
    iter++;
}
```

It is also used to return the element found in a `search()` or `find()` method.

**Do Something Useful**

The `search()` method returns a `bool` that simply tells whether the array contains the item or not. If that's really your intent, I'd rename it `contains()`. But it would probably be more useful to return either the index of the item in the array (or at least of the first occurrence in the array), or return an iterator that points to that instance.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the two reviews above, I do not see a destructor here freeing the memory held in `array` pointer. You should use RAII as the main purpose of it is to allow implementers to control class resources. You should use something like:

```
MemoryList(std::size_t seed = 10)
{
    //...
    array = new Heap[length];
}

~MemoryList()
{
    delete[] array;
}
```

This of course will make your `finished` function obsolete since the user should *never* be allowed to make handle resources explicitly (that's the point of RAII).

You use a *signed* value to represent a value that *should always be positive* (seed and length). As someone from above recommended, use `std::size_t` for all your values. This also allows you to have a `MemoryList` that can grow to be much bigger than 2^31 - 1 elements since `std::size_t` is either an `unsigned long` or `unsigned long long` type.

An algorithm like "search" is already available in the STL (`std::find`). Your class should provide an iterator interface that allows the users to be able to "plug-in" your data structure to the available STL algorithms. Your `shiftRight` function can be replaced by a call to `std::copy()` in `<algorithm>` and your `swap` function can be replaced by a call to `std::swap()` in `<algorithm>` as well.

Your `insertValue` and `newValue` functions take a `Heap` argument by value - which means it's passed by copy. What if the `Heap` type is expensive to construct/copy? Use a constant reference to a `Heap` type instead:

```
void insertValue(std::size_t position, const Heap& value);
void newValue(const Heap& value);
```

Your `showValue` function should really be transformed into a `operator[]` member overload and return a reference to the object it's showing. You'll have to provide a const and non-const version of these:

```
Heap& operator[](std::size_t i);
const Heap& operator[](std::size_t i) const;
```

In your `refine` function, you're using the `i` variable twice inside `for` loops yet you've declared it non-local to those loops. Declare the `i` variable to be local to the loop:

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; /*...*/){ /*...*/ }
```

You also might want to implement some convenience functions for the user of your data structure like returning the size or returning whether or not your structure is empty:

```
bool isEmpty() const;
std::size_t size() const;
```

Finally, the `inline` specifier is unnecessary if you're implementing the function in the header definition file (as you are in this case).